# C# : Uploading a document to SharePoint 2010 using Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010, upload, custom-controls

Im having some trouble. I have a document library that contains a custom column ("Category"), this is just a lookup from the "Category" List.

I am able to upload the document successfully, however i sould like to set that category list aswell.

I am uploading to the document library using the SharePoint web services located here : [sharepointurl]/_vti_bin/copy.asmx

Regards
Jean

Answer (score 1):

Once you have uploaded the document you can use "UpdateListItems" in lists.asmx to update the column you want for the new item.